# assign whole object for ng-value and retrieve in controller when the a particular radio button is checked

Tags: angularjs

I want to assign and retrieve the whole object to ng-value on ng-repeat. And when I select a row of table using radio button, I want to get the object of the selected row.

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
<table id="remark-table">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Remarks</th>
         <th>Indicator</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="data in remarks track by data.id">
         <td>{{data.name}}</td>
         <td>{{data.remarks}}</td>
         <td><input type="radio" name="indicator" ng-model=data ng-value=data></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$scope.remarks = [{
  name : 'John',
  remarks : 'Remark 1'
},
{
  name : 'Tom',
  remarks : 'Remark 2'
},
{
  name : 'Jerry',
  remarks : 'Remark 3'
}];

$scope.save = function() {
    var remarks = angular.element('#remark-table tbody tr td').find('input[name="indicator"]:checked').val();
}
```

remarks is returned as [object Object]

Fiddle is not opening at the moment. Hence posted the code here. Kindly help with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this in the html:

```
<input type="radio" name="indicator" ng-model="$parent.data" ng-value="data">
```

And in the controller you can get it like this:

```
$scope.save = function() {
   var remarks = $scope.data;
}
```

Didnt actually tested, so try it out and see if it works...

Comment: Thank u very much.. that was perfect!